# laravel-localization cannot change locale via URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization

I use laravel-localization for multiple language (tr-en).

When I click website.com/en/example and then click website.com/tr/ornek URL become website.com/en/ornek.

Is this about cache? I dont know why, how to solve this?